# How to capture the output of find command in a batch file to a variable

Tags: batch-file

```
FOR /F %%G IN ( 'find /i "%Today%" ^< db_backup_%Today%.log') DO (        
   set T=%%G
)    
echo %T%
```

Here, Today is the Today timestamp - `yyyymmdd` format. I am searching for this match in the file called `db_backup_%Today%.log` file which I generated already.

I want to save the output (eg: `2013-04-24-07.26.18`) of the find command to a variable T.

Comment: post the content of the log please

Comment: Your code will do that as it stands.  You can add the "delims=" so that it captures the entire line though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (see [@foxidrive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2299431/foxidrive)'s comment):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('find /i "%Today%" ^< db_backup_%Today%.log') DO (        
   set "T=%%G"
)    
echo %T%
```

Comment: What @foxidrive said is a bad practice, Delimitting none is a bad practice, consider to edit using "Tokens=*" instead of.

Comment: @Elektro Hacker No, `"Tokens=*"`is invalid. It can change the value of a string!